# Solving for $\Gamma^c_{ab}$ Christoffel symbols from the metric $g_{ab}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, covariance

I am trying to compute the Christoffel symbols $\Gamma^c_{ab}$ to have a metric-compatible covariant derivative $\nabla_a g_{bc}=0$. I worked out $$\nabla_a g_{bd}=\partial_a g_{bd}-\Gamma^{c}_{ab}Y_{cd}-\Gamma^{c}_{ad}g_{bc}$$ for rank-2 tensors. Thus, in order to get zero:

> $$\partial_a g_{bd} = \Gamma_{ab}^c g_{cd} + \Gamma^c_{ad} g_{bc}.$$

However, I am unsure of how to solve for $\Gamma^c_{ab}$ from here. I tried to contract it with $g^{bd}$ but I just obtain $2\Gamma^b_{ab}=g^{bd}\partial_a g_{bd}$, which is a particular case.

Comment: If I knew that $\Gamma$ looks something like $g(\partial g + \partial g -\partial g)$, I would re-write the quoted equation two more times with appropriately exchanged index names; add two of the three and subtract the third to see what happens. ;-)

Comment: Fair enough, I think I have that expression :)

Comment: It does check! I will try to understand why it happened...

Comment: I believe that you mean metric-compatible and torsion free

Comment: @JerrySchirmer mm actually this is part of an exercise with non-zero torsion so I think it is not needed and we have $T^c_{ab}=2\Gamma^{c}_{[ab]}$. But I am a newbie so it is very likely that I am wrong...

Comment: No, that's the correct expression for torsion.  I just saw J.G.'s answer below and thought that's what you were doing.

Answer (score 2):

Similarly (by cycling indices), $\partial_bg_{da}=\Gamma_{bd}^cg_{ca}+\Gamma_{ba}^cg_{dc}$ and $\partial_dg_{ab}=\Gamma_{da}^cg_{bc}+\Gamma_{db}^cg_{ac}$. Combining the three equations (and using $g_{uv}=g_{vu},\,\Gamma_{uv}^w=\Gamma_{vu}^w$ to alphabetize certain index pairs),$$\begin{align}\partial_ag_{bd}+\partial_bg_{ad}-\partial_dg_{ab}&=\Gamma_{ab}^cg_{cd}+\Gamma_{ad}^cg_{bc}+\Gamma_{bd}^cg_{ac}+\Gamma_{ab}^cg_{cd}-\Gamma_{ad}^cg_{bc}-\Gamma_{bd}^cg_{ac}\\&=2\Gamma_{ab}^cg_{cd},\\\Gamma_{ab}^e&=\delta_c^e\Gamma_{ab}^c\\&=\tfrac12g^{de}2\Gamma_{ab}^cg_{cd}\\&=\tfrac12g^{de}(\partial_ag_{bd}+\partial_bg_{ad}-\partial_dg_{ab}).\end{align}$$

Comment: Indeed! I was wondering whether there was any systematic way to solve this kind of equations in case they appear in the exam but I guess I just need more experience to see them right away...

Comment: @BrainOverflow Exploiting index symmetries to get more bang for your buck is the main systematic thing to learn here.